# Understanding nat_ind2 in Logical Foundations

Tags: coq, logical-foundations, proof-assistant

As an alternative induction principle of nat, `nat_ind2` is defined like so:

```
Definition nat_ind2 :
  forall (P : nat -> Prop),
  P 0 ->
  P 1 ->
  (forall n : nat, P n -> P (S(S n))) ->
  forall n : nat , P n :=
    fun P => fun P0 => fun P1 => fun PSS =>
      fix f (n:nat) := match n with
                         0 => P0
                       | 1 => P1
                       | S (S n') => PSS n' (f n')
                       end.
```

If my IDE isn't wrong, function `f` has the type `nat -> nat`. But I thought `PSS` requires something of the type `P n` in its second argument, so why is `f` typed like so?

Also, is there a way to define nat_ind2 as a `Fixpoint`? I tried this:

```
Fixpoint nat_ind (P : nat -> Prop) (P0 : P 0) (P1 : P 1) 
  (PSS : forall n : nat, P n -> P (S (S n))) (n : nat) :=
  fix PK := 
  match n with
  | 0 => P0
  | 1 => P1
  | S (S k) => PSS k (PK k)
  end.
```

But it doesn't work. The main difficulty I think is that `PK` can't be annotated to take the right type (`P k`). I'm pretty new to coq, so there's probably something I'm missing.

Edit: My IDE is probably wrong, the type of `f` should be `forall n:nat, P n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With recent Coq (8.18) you can write:

```
Fixpoint nat_ind2 (P : nat -> Prop) (P0 : P 0) (P1 : P 1) 
  (PSS : forall n : nat, P n -> P (S (S n))) (n : nat) :=
  match n with
  | 0 => P0
  | 1 => P1
  | S (S k) => PSS k (nat_ind2 P P0 P1 PSS k)
  end.

About nat_ind2.
```

which gives

```
nat_ind2 :
forall P : nat -> Prop,
P 0 ->
P 1 ->
(forall n : nat, P n -> P (S (S n))) -> forall n : nat, P n
```

I think this was not always possible - the consistency checker for fixpoints has been improved over time.

But there are reasons for using the more complicated design above with a local fixpoint: you can pass only the one changing argument and keep all others from the outer function. If functions are used for computation, this does make a performance / stack space difference, but for induction principles which are usually only used in opaque proofs, this doesn't make a difference and IMHO the simpler variant without a local fixpoint definition is preferable.